# Finding value in a SQL table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a simple question here (I know it is so simple but I just got stuck...)

I have a table
tag_id, search_id
1,1
2,1
4,2
2,2
5,2

I would like to get the search_id by giving the tag_ids
example: 
tag_id 1,2 would return search_id 1
tag_id 4,2,5 would return search_id 2
tag_id 2,6 would return no result.

I should have pay more attention when I was in college... 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT search_id 
FROM YourTable
WHERE tag_id IN (4,2,5)
GROUP BY search_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 3 /*Adjust this as required*/
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the IN clause an exact equivalent to WHERE  (tag_ID = 4 OR tag_ID = 2 OR tag_ID = 5) ?

Comment: @Tom - Semantically yes. I'm not sure if MySQL's query optimiser treats it any differently though.

Comment: Cool! thanks, looks nice and seems working good here!

Owe you a beer there!!! :)